# Problemas com variáveis php em HTML <span>

Tags: php, html

Eu estou tentando montar um emissor de formulários, para agilizar minha vida e não ter que pegar um arquivo no Word e ter que alterar vários campos em vários documentos com o mesmo dado.
Usei um conversor de PDF para HTML e ele usa uma variável  para reproduzir as letras. O problema é que, por causa disso, não to conseguindo ler a variável em si...
Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
session_start();
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
?>
</head>
<?php
print "<body>\n";
print "<div style='position:absolute;top:3.66in;left:1.73in;width:5.58in;line-height:0.20in;'></span><span style='font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;font-family:Arial-BoldMT;color:#000000'>$nome</span>";
print "</body>\n";
?>
```

E sempre que vou ver o arquivo está escrito **$nome** em vez do nome da pessoa. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Você salvou essa pagina com extensão .php  exemplo pagina.php  ? ou salvou com extensão .html ?

Comment: A página está sim como .php

Comment: Testei no meu servidor e rodou bem. Unico problema é warning devido a seesion start após output

Comment: O problema é que no meu está dando $nome em vez do nome... Teria alguma forma de mostrar isso?

Comment: Eu consegui dessa vez... Eu troquei todos os print por echos... Eles estavam me dando problemas de formatação, e entre o código eu montei um echo com a variavel.

Comment: coloca esses <html>
<head> depois da tag PHP. Deixe session_start na primeira linha do php para não gerar erro

Comment: aqui funcionou com print também. Se já resolveu então seja feliz

Answer (score 0):

Se colocar assim talvez seja uma solução(não tenho certeza)

```
print "<div style='position:absolute;top:3.66in;left:1.73in;width:5.58in;line-height:0.20in;'></span><span style='font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;font-family:Arial-BoldMT;color:#000000'>".$nome."</span>";
```